# The links in my drop down menu are not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to jquery, html, and css.When ever I tried to link to another page in my drop down menu the links do not work. I used jquery for the drop down menu and it works like I want it to work not sure what could possible be the problem?

The error is not with the drop down menu it is with the links in my a href they do not work when you click on them.
css

```
nav#menu {
float: right;
margin-right: 150px;
}

nav#menu #menu-nav {
margin: 0;
padding: 0; 
}

nav#menu #menu-nav li {
list-style: none;
display: inline-block;
}

nav#menu #menu-nav ul li a{
background: black;
width: 250px;
}

nav#menu #menu-nav li a {
color: #DE5E60;
font-size: 18px;
font-weight: 300;
line-height: 60px;
display: block;
padding-right: 1cm;
text-transform: uppercase;
}

nav#menu #menu-mav ul ul li{
  padding-right: 1cm;
}

nav#menu #menu-nav li a:hover {
color: #FFFFFF;
}


nav#menu ul ul{
position:absolute;
width:400px;
display:none;
}

nav#menu ul ul li{
display:block;
background:#252525;
}
```

html

```
<header>
   <div class="sticky-nav">
      <a id="mobile-nav" class="menu-nav" href="#menu-nav"></a>
    <div id="logo">
    <a href="#projects">
        <img alt="" src="pictures/Logo.jpg" width="157px"   height="114px">
    </a>
    </div>

<nav id="nav">
    <nav id="menu">
        <ul id="menu-nav">
            <li><a href="#projects">Links</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="https://www.google.com/">google</a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://www.yahoo.com/">yahoo</a></li>
                    <li><a href="link1.html">Link 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="link2.html">Link 2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#Services">Services</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="https://www.google.com/">google</a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://www.yahoo.com/">yahoo</a></li>
                    <li><a href="link1.html">Link 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="link2.html">Link 2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</nav>
</div>
```

jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {

   $("#menu ul li").on('mouseover',function() {
    $(this).find("ul").stop().slideToggle(400);
   });

    $("#menu ul li").on('mouseout',function() {
    $(this).find("ul").stop().slideToggle(400);
   });  
 });
</script>
```

Comment: We don't like playing "find the error in the stacktrace" please be more specific! What doesn't work? What debugging have you done?

Comment: Works for me in chrome except where the jsfiddle and chrome won't let me click on google and yahoo due to iframe issues https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/h56xwrwo/

Comment: I'm running chrome and it all works fine for the services dropdown. Not sure what the problem is.

Comment: Works fine here and in jsfiddle ...

Comment: The problem is when you click on the link you would be redirected to the page.

Comment: Does it have to do with my jquery I changed it to

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#menu ul li").hover(function() {
      $(this).find("ul").stop().slideToggle(400);
     });

Comment: but that still was not working for the links

Comment: You can't display Google or Yahoo in a frame, and that is the problem with  jsFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
ul, ul li {
    pointer-events:none;
}
a {
    pointer-events:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found 2 different problems that have caused my links to not work on a Web-Page:

1. If I download a Web-Page using Google Chrome ( so that I can reverse engineer the page ), the first 3 lines of the file are as follows  ( I don't know why I couldn't get the first line of this HTML code to appear in the highlighted box, so I finally had to put a space after the  <  in order to get SOMETHING to print.
   And by the way, what is a backtick ? )

< !DOCTYPE html >

```
<!--  saved from url=(0116)https://www.imdb.com/ ... other stuff ...  -->

<html lang="en-US">
```

When you download the Web-Page off of the internet, Google Chrome inserts the comment in the second line, so that you will know where the Web-Page came from.  Now, get ready for this, the thing that causes the links to not work is the 2'nd line ... the COMMENT !

If you have a comment at the top of your page, and if you delete the comment, then the links ( down in the < body > of your HTML file ) will magically start to work.

2. I have seen the following code cause links to not work:

...

```
<div class="main">

    ... various other HTML code ...

<a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0WxdcL_hBxU">

    <img src="thumbnail-photo.jpg">

</a>

</div>
```

...

CSS Code:

```
.main { 
    ... various css code ...

    z-index=-1; 
}
```

In this example 2, I have written code that allows you to click on an Image, and you get re-directed to a YouTube video.   The thing that causes the link to NOT work is the  CSS code:   z-index=-1

If you change the value to  z-index=0, then the links will work fine.